# How to extract a key value pair from a nested dictionary and output it in json

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

I am extracting part of a dictionary with

```
with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data['metadata'], outfile)
```

So that I get the value of 'metadata' and none of the key value pairs before. How do I modify it so I also get the key itself ('metadata') to appear in the output before the value? I tried this

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
   if key is "metadata":
       val = my_dict[key]
```

and then using `json.dump(val, outfile)` but that created an error `global name val is not defined` (I defined it as a global variable earlier to try to fix an earlier error message.) I can't use just "data" itself because there is a key value pair in data that I want to exclude.

Comment: note that `json.dump` can only dump something that actually makes sense as JSON, so if you want the key to also appear in your output than what you probably want to output is a dict consisting of only the one key: `json.dump({'metadata': data['metadata']}, outfile)`

Comment: that works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
    json.dump({'metadata': data['metadata']} , outfile)
```